# Double click in file input not working on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, input

I have an issue in file input.

When I open file input window and in file explorer I double click on jpg I would like to upload the window closes without uploading photo.

When I click on photo and submit it with 'open' button it uploads.

It happens only on Firefox, on Chrome is fine.

my code:

```
export const ImageSelector = ({

  const handleFileChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };


  return (
   <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
  );
};
```